# Homebrew not installed to /usr/local

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I'm trying to get a new computer set up and installed Homebrew with `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"` following the instructions on their home page. The problem is, when I ran `brew doctor` it gave me this error: `Your Homebrew is not installed to /usr/local You can install Homebrew anywhere you want, but some brews may only build correctly if you install in /usr/local. Sorry!`

When I did the install from terminal I was in the Home directory.

From what I've read Homebrew is supposed to install to `/usr/local` by default so I'm not sure how I screwed this up...

Any ideas how to get Homebrew installed to the correct location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when I installed RVM it also installs Homebrew. More info here: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/19454#issuecomment-17086674

Comment: If I remember correctly I needed to install Homebrew first, then install RVM